# Is this a quote: "Everyone is special, but not everyone is equal, vs everyone is equal, but not everyone is special"?

Tags: quotes

I heard a friend use the sentence to describe the contrast between personal world-views, or even political parties:

> In their world, everyone is special but not everyone is equal. In our world, everyone is equal, but not everyone is special.

My question is: is this a quote, if so what is the origin:  *"Everyone is special, but not everyone is equal, vs everyone is equal, but not everyone is special"*?**

Comment: Did you ask your friend whether they'd come up with it?

Comment: Not Orwell's pigs. They announced "All animals are equal, but some are more equal than others"! Sounds to me that your quotation is a less succinct effort to say the same thing.

Comment: It sounds like your friend came up with this particular wording, or maybe copied directly from someone else who did. If you think it's especially eloquent, ask your friend if they "said it" and compliment them if they did. ("Regular" people can sometimes turn a fine phrase!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of question comes up often: The **specific sentence you typed**, is simply *not* 'a quote', nor is it an idiom or figure of speech.

Rather: it's commonplace in English today, that people **mangle** figures of speech, or mangle specific quotes.

What you heard is a commonplace sentiment, but the version you heard is simply mangled.

(It may be literally be just a typo, or just a mis-speaking.)

The particular sentiment in the question is often heard, with many different variations. Here's just one excellent example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8I9pYCl9AQ

[image]

flawless delivery there in the Brad Bird film!

What you heard in the example given in the question is, very simply, a mangled, messy, version of the same sentiment.

As WS2 pointed out, the sentiment can be seen in for example Orwell's Animal Farm.  Naturally, in Orwell it is perfectly expressed with flawless grammar. (I don't know if that's the "earliest expression" of it: unlikely; impossible to know.)

So to reiterate:

1. It is not a quote.
2. You will not find a 'source' for the quote since ... it is not a quote!
3. It is not a figure of speech
4. It is not an idiom
5. It's simply a "mangled" - just plain incorrect, simply mis-spoken, muddled-up - version of an idea you often hear expressed.

To repeat, it is very common in English today - both personal speech and professional presentations - that people "mix up" or "rehash" common sentiments and/or quotes and/or figures of speech, using confused or plain grammatically incorrect phrasing.  Your example is a perfect example of that.

Comment: Answer comes across as hostile and angry rather than informative.